# jQuery country redirection portal

Tags: jquery

OK the scenario is this, I have multiple country unique websites, I want to send all my clients one e-marketing email and since emails don't allow scripts I want the links to direct the user to there correct country website via a portal/redirect page.

**Link in the email:**

```
<a href="http://www.website.com/redirect#about-us/contact">Contact Us</a>
```

**Code on the redirect page:**

```
$(window).load(function () {

    $.getJSON('http://api.wipmania.com/jsonp?callback=?', function (data) {

        var hash = location.hash.slice(1);
        var country = data.address.country;
        var urls = {
            'Australia': 'www.website.com.au',
            'New Zealand': 'www.website.co.nz'
        }

        var cchUrl = 'www.website.com';
        if(urls[country]) {
            cchUrl = urls[country];
        }

        //alert(cchUrl+'/'+hash);
        var url =cchUrl+'/'+hash;
        window.location.href = url;
    });
})
```

I have some code almost working! (so proud because i'm just learning) but I cant get it to redirect properly as I get the result below:

```
http://www.website.com/www.website.co.nz/about-us/contact
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `.href` it's just `window.location`. Also add the `http://` to fully qualify the URL, otherwise it's being considered relative to the current page.

```
window.location = 'http://' + url;
```

Comment: Hmmm im still getting the double up http://www.website.com/www.website.co.nz/about-us/contact

Comment: @webmonkey237 Fixed in the edit. You have to add the http:// part of the URL otherwise it's being considered relative to the current page.

Comment: @webmonkey237 Though this works 99% of the time, the redirect should really be server side. If a user comes to your page with javascript turned off, this will break. If you use javascript to redirect, make sure the current page is the default. If you have to redirect to the default, then this is "broken".

Comment: Do you know of a better way or am i close, I approached this from one way of thinking and very open to a better solution, the only thing that was important was not having to add a script to every page on my site to make sure the user is from the right country. Maybe even like some sort of fail safe on the redirect page like a javascript warning?

Comment: you could do the detection and redirect on server side in php or asp or whatever language your site is coded it.

Comment: Unfortunatly what i'm working with is a closed piece of online software/CMS so I cant work with anything else.